# php json object reading

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a web page written in php where i get some info about the user from his linked in profile, thanks to linked in API. It gives me the following json object. with :

```
$user = json_decode($response);
```

method i decode the following json object into $user object.

```
{ "firstName": "Tolga", "lastName": "Evcimen", "skills": { "_total": 2, "values": [ { "id": 1, "skill": {"name": "Microsoft Office"} }, { "id": 2, "skill": {"name": "Microsoft Excel"} } ] } }
```

what i can't is to work with these values, my php knowledge is a little low, that's why i don't know how to read skills or anything else. The only thing I could read so far is :

```
$user->firstName , $user->lastName
```

but I can't get the rest with same approach :(

```
$user->skills->values[1]->skill->name, or $user->skills->_total
```

please give me some information about these things

Comment: Do you get the same using $user['skills'] instead of $user->skills? When using {}, you're not creating actual PHP objects, but associative arrays. I would use $user['skills']['values'][1]['skill']['name']

Comment: `var_dump($user)` will let you see the actual structure of what you get by json_decode. Then it will be trivial.

Comment: Once you have it in `$user` do a `print_r` or `var_dump` to see the structure

Comment: Works fine for me with the JSON you posted: http://codepad.org/RvYCLvNI. We cannot really help you if the code and everything else you post actually works.

Comment: `->skills->values[1]->skill->name` works here if I decode that thing...

Comment: @Alejandro: By default, JSON encoded objects are converted to objects of class `stdClass`, not arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot, it turned out I made some other mistakes in the code, instead of echo I used print, and kinda mixed it up in a bad way. thats why I couldn't achive the right behaviour in code.

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,skills)');
print "\n <\br> Hello $user->firstName $user->lastName."; 
print " $user->skills->values[0]->skill->name";
echo $user->skills->values[0]->skill->name;
exit;
```

doesn't work :)

```
echo "\n <\br> Hello $user->firstName $user->lastName.";  
echo $user->skills->values[0]->skill->name;
```

works fine.

Grateful for your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
echo $user->firstName;
echo $user->skills->values[0]->id;
echo $user->skills->values[0]->skill->name;
```

Results:

```
Tolga
1
Microsoft Office
```

Test it on PHP fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x18-z6f

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem with this, maybe post a code example so we can see where you went wrong.

```
$user->skills->values[1]->skill->name
```

Example:

```
<?php
    $response = '{
      "firstName": "Tolga",
      "lastName": "Evcimen",
      "skills": {
        "_total": 2,
        "values": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "skill": {
              "name": "Microsoft Office"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "skill": {
              "name": "Microsoft Excel"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }';

    $user = json_decode($response);

    var_dump($user->skills->values[1]);

?>
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["skill"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "Microsoft Excel"
  }
}
```